# Basic 3 Round Card Game

Tags: python, beginner, python-2.x, random, playing-cards

Feel free to critique my code and offer suggestions on how to clean it up and make it more presentable. I have been working on this for a few days, and learning as I go.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import random
import sys


#Global variables

dealerWins = 0
playerWins = 0
dealerCard = [1,2,3,4,5]
playersCard = [1,2,3,4,5]


def main():
    intro()


def intro(): #Intro to game; asking for deposit of money into bank variable
    print ('Welcome to the Back Alley Gambling Club!')
    try:
        bank = int(raw_input('How much money would you like to put in your account?: '))
        if bank < 1:
            print ("Sorry, input must be a positive integer, try again", '')
            intro()
    except ValueError:
        print('Please input a valid positive integer')
        intro()
    bankString = str(bank)
    print ('Do you want to put $'+bankString + ' into your account?')
    checkBet = raw_input('Type \'y\' or \'n\': ')
    if checkBet == 'y':
        bet(bank)
    else: intro()

def bet(bank): #Ask how much you want to wager
        print ('How much would you like to wager?: ', end="")
        try:
            wager = int(raw_input())
            if wager > bank:
                print ('Your bet must be less than or equal to what is in your bank.  Please try again.')
                bet(bank)
            else: checkBet(wager, bank)
        except ValueError:
            print('Please input a valid integer')
            bet(bank)

def checkBet(wager,bank):   
        wagerString = str(wager)    
        print ('Awesome!  You want to bet $'+ wagerString +  ' is that right?:  ')
        check = raw_input('Type \'y\' or \'n\': ')
        if check == 'y':

            print ('Awesome, lets play!')
            cardGame(wager, bank)
        elif checkBet == 'n':
            print ('Lets try again, shall we?')
            checkBet(wager)
        else: 
            print ('Please try again')
            checkBet(wager)

def cardGame(wager,bank): #main logic of card game
    dealerHand = (random.choice(dealerCard))
    playersHand = (random.choice(playersCard))
    print ('The Dealers card is', dealerHand)
    print ('The Players card is', playersHand)


    if dealerHand > playersHand: 
        print ('Dealer wins!')
        global dealerWins
        dealerWins+=1
        if dealerWins<2:
            print ('Dealer has',dealerWins, 'victory!')
        else: print ('Dealer has', dealerWins,'victories!')
    elif dealerHand < playersHand: 
        print ('Player wins!')
        global playerWins
        playerWins+=1
        if playerWins<2:
            print ('Player has', playerWins,'victory!')
        else: print ('Player has', playerWins,'victories!')
    else: print ('Push.  Its a tie.')

    if dealerWins < 3 and playerWins < 3:
        print ('One more round.')
        raw_input('Press enter to continue!')
        cardGame(wager, bank)

    elif dealerWins >= 3:
        print ('Dealer wins the game!')
        bank = bank-wager
        print ('You now have ', bank, 'in your bank.')
        playAgain(wager, bank)

    else: 
        print ('Player wins the game!')
        bank = bank + wager
        print ('You now have ', bank, 'in your bank.')
        playAgain(wager, bank)

def playAgain(wager, bank): #play again
    global dealerWins 
    global playerWins
    dealerWins =0
    playerWins = 0
    if bank <=0:
        entry = raw_input('Would you like to play again?  Type \'y\' or type \'n\' : ' )
        if entry == 'y':
            intro()
        elif entry == 'n':
            print ('Have a great day!')
            sys.exit()
        else: print ('Please type either \'y\' or \'n\'.  Thank you!: ')
        playAgain(wager, bank)
    elif bank >0:
        entry = raw_input('Would you like to play again?  Type \'y\' or type \'n\' : ' )
        if entry == 'y':
            bet(bank)
        elif entry == 'n':
            print ('Have a great day!')
            sys.exit()
        else: print ('Please type either \'y\' or \'n\'.  Thank you!: ')
        playAgain(wager, bank)

main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## PEP 8

Please follow the [PEP 8 style guide](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). So, as some quick examples:

1. Use `snake_case` i.e. `playAgain -> play_again`
2. Add spaces between your operators: `dealerWins =0 -> dealer_wins = 0`
3. Add two spaces between each function.

There may be some others. Please read the link so you can find the issues, or run [pylint](https://www.pylint.org/) on your code to correct all of these issues.

## Structure

You *really* should avoid using global variables unless you absolutely have to. In this case, you don't need them.

### Classes

Given that you have some global state at the moment, it might be a good idea to write a class describing your game.

```
class CardGame:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.dealer_wins = 0
        self.player_wins = 0

    ...
```

If you have issues understanding what classes are please read [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).

## Function Structure

The flow of your program is a bit weird. Your `intro` goes to `bet` which goes to `checkBet`, which then goes to the main `cardGame` function. I think having an `intro` is fine. The transition from `intro` to `bet` is fine as well. The issue I have is you call card game from `checkBet`. Your `checkBet` should determine if the bet is valid. Then if it is, let the function `bet` proceed into `cardGame`. *Don't* proceed from `checkBet`.

## Redundant string calls.

`wagerString = str(wager)` and `bankString = str(bank)` are unnecessary, just use the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

#### Repetition in input handling

There is so much repetition in input handling that the logic is almost obscured by it.

I would write a general function:

```
def ask_until(prompt, validation=lambda x:True, error_message=""):
    x = input(prompt)
    while not validation(x):
        print(error_message)
        x = input(prompt)
    return x

def is_integer_and_within(lower, upper):
    return lambda x: all(d in "1234567890" for d in x) and lower < x < upper
```

An use it like:

```
def bet(bank): #Ask how much you want to wager
    wager = ask_until(
      'How much would you like to wager?: ',
      is_integer_and_within(1, bank),
      'Your bet must be less than or equal to what is in your bank.  Please try again.'
    )
    checkBet(wager, bank)
```

The same function(s) can be used in other places in your code.